# AWS CloudEndure migration specifics

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, server-migration

My company plans on using AWS CloudEndure to migrate bunch of on-site HyperV servers to aws cloud.
I want to specifically know what folder structure is being migrated, and have not been able to find it anywhere. For example, if theres VScode with very specific configuration and plugins on those servers, is all that configuration migrated as well? does that mean that "/user/appdata/.vscode" folder is being migrated?
I understand that agent migrates all the server volumes to EBS cluster and then they are being replicated in EC2 instances, but

**Can anybody show an example of files structure that is being migrated?**

Answer (score 0):

CloudEndure does a block level replication for your disks, so you will end up having identical replica on your AWS target

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine check the logs at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cloudendure\agent.log.0`
to get the details on what the agent is working on.

Answer (score 0):

CloudEndure works at disk level, It is going replicate data on the disk, CloudEndure works with Re-Hosting(Lift and Shift) method. Once the replication done, you can use migrated server as same as your on-premise server but on AWS.